# Fibre Channel Adapter as a NIC?

Tags: ethernet, nic, fibre-channel

Is it possible to use a Fibre Channel PCIe adapter as an Ethernet network interface? I have QLogic Fibre Channel controller and a 3Com Gigabit Ethernet switch. I use Debian on a DL160 G5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use a Fibre Channel PCIe adapter as a network
> interface?

Certainly you can run IP on FC ([RFC 2625](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2625)) but it'll never work with your switch as that's specifically an Ethernet switch, it would need to connect to an FC switch.

By the way, just because you *can* do this doesn't make it a good idea, in fact it's a staggeringly rare setup, for all purposes it's a dangerously bad idea - but you asked if it *could* be done.